# How do I get the ELSE part of IF statement to output custom message when condition is not met in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to use an IF statement to output a gender/sex count if the table contains either gender or sex. I am using R markdown and want it to output a message such as "No gender/sex variable in this dataset"  and move to the next block if there is no gender/sex variable in the dataset. If I run my code on a table that contain gender or sex it runs without any problem, but if the table does not contain gender or sex it will throw an error "Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", I want my own custom message instead of an error. below is my code:

```
sex_or_gender <- location %>%
  select_if(names(.) %in% "sex" | names(.) %in% "gender")

if(names(location) %in% "sex" || names(location) %in% "gender") {
    sex_or_gender %>%
        group_by(sex_or_gender[1] %>%
        summarise(sex_count = n())
} else{
     print("No gender/sex variable in this dataset")
}

Result should be either;
|sex| sex_count|
| M |   256    |
| F |   301    |
| NA|   25     |
```

or

```
|gender| sex_count|
|   M  |   256    |
|   F  |   301    |
|   NA |   25     |
```

or

```
No gender/sex variable in this dataset
```

NOTE: The returned data frame contains only one variable, either sex or date depending on which is used

Comment: Please provide some example data by pasting the output of `dput` of your data, so we can better help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick is using **any()** in the conditions

```r
library(dplyr)
name <- c("john", "sue", "terrence", "amy.Smith")
height <- c(68, 62, 66, 70)
weight <- c(170, 110, 155, NA)
sex <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female")
gender <- c("0", "1", "2", "2")
loc1 <- data.frame(
  name = name,
  height = height,
  Weight = weight,
  sex = sex,
  gender = gender
)

loc2 <- data.frame(
  name = name,
  height = height,
  Weight = weight
)

sex_or_gender <- loc1 %>%
  select_if(names(.) %in% "sex" | names(.) %in% "gender")

if (any(names(loc1) %in% "sex") || any(names(loc1) %in% "gender")) {
  sex_or_gender %>%
    group_by(sex_or_gender[1]) %>%
    summarise(sex_count = n())
}
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   sex    sex_count
#> * <fct>      <int>
#> 1 Female         2
#> 2 Male           2

sex_or_gender <- loc2 %>%
  select_if(names(.) %in% "sex" | names(.) %in% "gender")

if (any(names(loc2) %in% "sex") || any(names(loc2) %in% "gender")) {
  sex_or_gender %>%
    group_by(sex_or_gender[1]) %>%
    summarise(sex_count = n())
} else {
  print("No gender/sex variable in this dataset")
}
#> [1] "No gender/sex variable in this dataset"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, This really helped.